# How to get id of div or anchor tag ,when clicked , with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get id of `<div>` or an `<a>` by clicking it. Please help...

```
<div class="reccl" id="allact"><a href="#" class="a" id="b">All Activities</a></div>
<div class="reccl" id="lgns"><a href="#" class="a" id="bb">Logins</a></div>
<div class="reccl" id="dwld"><a href="#" class="a" id="bb">Download</a></div>
```

javascript code:

```
 var a = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
     for(var b = 0; b <= a.length; b++){
        a[i].onclick = function(e){
            alert("id clicked");
        }
     }
```

code here: http://jsfiddle:%20http://jsfiddle.net/mm07p5rz/

Comment: either through what or a tag?

Answer (score 3):

Just get the `id` property of the click event's `target` object. By the way, `id`s should be unique in the document.

This will get the `id` of any element clicked on the page:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  console.log(evt.target.id);
});
```

```html
<div class="reccl" id="allact"><a href="#" class="a" id="b">All Activities</a></div>
<div class="reccl" id="lgns"><a href="#" class="a" id="bb">Logins</a></div>
<div class="reccl" id="dwld"><a href="#" class="a" id="bbb">Download</a></div>
```

This will get the `id` of any `<a>` element that was clicked. You can filter the particular elements any way you like, but the process to get the `id` is the same:

```js
// Get just and <a> elements
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");

// Set up a click event listener for each one
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
  anchors[i].addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    console.log(evt.target.id);
  }); 
}
```

```html
<div class="reccl" id="allact"><a href="#" class="a" id="b">All Activities</a></div>
<div class="reccl" id="lgns"><a href="#" class="a" id="bb">Logins</a></div>
<div class="reccl" id="dwld"><a href="#" class="a" id="bbb">Download</a></div>
```

Comment: `.addEventListener()` is the W3C DOM Event API standard for attaching event handling functions to events of DOM objects. `onclick`, `onXyz` will work, but is outdated and has drawbacks compared to `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: Thanks man... exactly what i was looking for... i was missing addeventlistener guy up there,,, Cheers mate...

Answer (score 0):

I edit your source code

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('reccl');
for (var b = 0; b < a.length; b++) {
 a[b].onclick = function(e){
  //get child's id in element
  alert(e.target.id);
  
  //get element's id
  alert(e.currentTarget.id);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="reccl" id="allact"><a href="#" class="a" id="b">All Activities</a></div>
<div class="reccl" id="lgns"><a href="#" class="a" id="bb">Logins</a></div>
<div class="reccl" id="dwld"><a href="#" class="a" id="bb">Download</a></div>
```

Comment: Whoa! A bit more than is necessary. No need to return a function from the event function. And, the returned function will always have `undefined` for its `e` argument.

Comment: @ScottMarcus My idea is: e.target will point to element you click inside parent and a[arg] will point to element, which fires onclick event. Of cause, the example can be written easier ^.^

Comment: What's the point of all that. Just assign a function to the event. No need to return a new function. That adds no value and just confuses the code.

Comment: Because I don't know him want to to get id of div(parent) or a(children) from div(parent) click. Returned new function allows get properly b value in for loop.

Comment: This same thing can be accomplished with `currentTarget` and event delegation, which is much simpler and doesn't involve any loops or returning new functions.

Comment: Thanks you Scott, I edited my answer as your suggestion.